# PCM5102A in 1.8V mode. Separate 0.1 and 10uF caps for DVDD an LDOO?

Tags: dac, decoupling-capacitor, decoupling

I found in the datasheet (33 page, 11.5.1) that when using PCM5102A in 1.8V mode, DVDD and LDOO should be both connected to external 1.8V. What's not clear to me is if I still have to put separate 0.1 and 10uF caps for both DVDD and LDOO pins as shown in the schematic provided in their datasheet. Here's how it looks like in my schematic:

[image]

Is this correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked forum talks only about XSMT. How to connect LDOO when your digital signals use 1.8 V is only mentioned there, but explained in the datasheet itself:

> When setting I/O voltage to be 1.8 V, both DVDD and LDOO must be provided with an external 1.8-V supply.

You do not need separate capacitors, because

- with both pins connected together, all capacitors are in parallel (and the pins are near enough so that the trace inductance should not matter); and
- the capacitor(s) on LDOO would be needed to decouple the internal LDO, but when you are feeding external power into this pin, the internal LDO is disabled, so you do not need bypassing anyway.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I found that information in the datasheet (33 page, 11.5.1). Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the explanation!